# Control parental en Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, intentservice

Mi proyecto es un control parental que filtra contenido explicito (pornografía) e implementación de búsqueda segura en los buscadores. Ya poseo los métodos para dichas acciones pero me he encontrado que en el momento de realizar la navegación en cualquier navegador móvil el resultado se muestra en una nueva pestaña y el objetivo es reemplazar el contenido de dicha pestaña por la página de bloqueo o por el resultado de la búsqueda segura.

el problema es que el resultado lo esta creando en una nueva pestaña y el objetivo es actualizar el contenido de dicha pestaña, o en otro caso, seria cerrar la pestaña y abrir una nueva con el resultado deseado

Este es el método para filtrado y búsqueda segura en Android.

```
    Filtro web;

     public void leena_primerf(final String url1)
        {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    url = "http://peerfy.co/api2/index.php?url=" + url1;

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                //@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //     Log.d("cual es la url", "el estado es : " + response + url1);
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String estado = jsonObject.getString("status");
                        int loco = Integer.parseInt(estado);
                        if (loco>0)
                        {
                            String urlco= url_codificada(url1);
                           // String urlString=("http://peerfy.co/bloqueoandroid/index.php?pk="+urlco);
                            String urlString=("http://localhost:5358/"+urlco);
                            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(urlString));
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.setPackage(Paquetefirefox);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) {
                        Log.d("problemas", "el estado es : " + ex);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override

        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }

    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

---

```
    Búsqueda segura;

     public void Safesearchg(String urlgoogle){
            String urlString=(urlgoogle.concat("&safe=strict"));
            Intent sharingIntentg = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            sharingIntentg.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            sharingIntentg.setData(Uri.parse(urlString));
            sharingIntentg.setPackage(Paquetechrome);
            Intent chooserIntentg = Intent.createChooser(sharingIntentg,                          "Open With");chooserIntentg.setPackage(Paquetechrome);startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntentg, "Open              With").setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)); }
```

Comment: Entonces cual es tu problema? No lo especificaste.

Comment: el problema es que el resultado lo esta creando en una nueva pestaña y el objetivo es actualizar el contenido de dicha pestaña, o en otro caso,  seria cerrar la pestaña y abrir una nueva con el resultado deseado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude solucionar lo de las pestañas utilizando este método

```
private void startBrowsergoogle(String url) {
    Browser browser = Browser.browsers.get(1);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(1082130436);
    intent.addFlags(-4194305);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "text/html");
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(browser.getPackage(), browser.getActivity()));
    intent.putExtra("com.android.browser.application_id", browser.getPackage());

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

para lo que no sepan que es addflags, Cuando lo usas, setFlags estás reemplazando las banderas antiguas ... cuando lo usas addFlags, añades nuevas banderas. Recuerda, una bandera es solo un entero que es potencia de dos ... en binario, las banderas se ven así: 1, 10, 100, 1000, etc. ... (que en este caso son 1, 2, 4, 8) . Entonces, ¿qué addFlags significa agregar el número entero que pasa con el |operador?

// ejemplo ...
// valor de banderas: 1
intent.setFlags (2 | 4);
// ahora las banderas tienen este valor: 110
intent.addFlags (8);
// ahora las banderas tienen este valor: 1110

Comment: ¿Pero que realiza esto? para que sirve addFlags(1082130436); y addFlags(-4194305); podrías explicar este código?